# Magento collection classes confusion

Tags: php, collection, model, resource-model, class

I confused by following collection classes

1. `$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');`
2. `$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order');`
3. `$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');`

   Whats the  difference among those classes.

And whats difference between

`Mage::getModel('sales/order');`

and

```
 Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order');
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')` = `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection` this is the resource for a collection of items in orders, normally the database table that this is attached to is sales_flat_order_item
2. `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')` = `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order` is the resource for a single sales orders and works with table sales_flat_order
3. `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')` = `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` and this is the resource for the collection of orders and uses the table sales_flat_order.

The main difference between models, resources and collections is described as follows:

1. Model: these classes are used to representing a single item normally from the database,
2. Resource: these classes are used to fetch and save data for an item to the database,
3. Collection: these classes are used to deal with more than one item from the database,

Answer (score -1):

They are all get different objects.
They are all different files.
They all serve different purposes.
See here on how to use collections:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento
See here for Magento Models and ORM Basics:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics